# Having problems with "ton" library in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api, ton

I'm using ton library and Python. This is the code I'm trying to run:

```py
from ton.sync import TonlibClient
client = TonlibClient()
TonlibClient.enable_unaudited_binaries()
client.init_tonlib()
seed = "24 security phrases"
wallet = client.import_wallet(seed)
balance = client.from_nano(wallet.get_balance())
print(balance)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test", line 13, in <module>
    print(wallet.get_balance())
  File     result = await self._execute(query, timeout=timeout)
ton.tonlibjson.TonlibError: LITE_SERVER_UNKNOWN: timeout(during last block synchronization)
```

This code worked fine before, but after a few days it started giving this error.
I'm running this on a DigitalOcean server so my internet isn't a problem. I've rebooted the server, reinstalled the library, changed server, but nothing works.